# How to preserve json formate after saving it into local storage?

Tags: javascript, json

```
function receivedText(e) {
  lines = e.target.result;
  obj = JSON.parse(lines);
  split();
}
function split() {
    console.log(obj);
    for (var i in obj) {
        console.log(i);     
        if(i=="tagClassifications"){
            console.log("tagClassifications IS MATCHED");
            var c1=obj[i];
            var ob2=JSON.stringify(c1);
            console.log(ob2);
            var obj1="{ \"tagClassifications\": "+ob2+" }";
            console.log(obj1);
            saveText(c1, "tagClassifications"+".json" );    
        }
        if(i=="tagAssociations"){
            console.log("tagAssociations IS MATCHED");
            var c1=obj[i];
            console.log(c1);
            for(var j in c1){
                console.log(c1[j]);
                console.log("Length="+c1.length+"j:"+j);
                var ob2=JSON.stringify(c1[j]);
                var obj1="{ tagAssociations"+": ["+ob2+"]}";
                console.log(obj1);
                saveText(obj1, "tagAssociations"+j+".json" );                                   
            }               
        }
    }       
}
function saveText(text, filename){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(text));
    a.setAttribute('download', filename);
    a.click();
}
```

In Above javascript I am converting a json object into text file and saving it as a json formate. But saved json file having extension as .json, but format is as a plain text. plz tell me how to preserve json format.

Comment: JSON is just text - what "format" do you want to preserve?

Comment: format means when we open it in notepad++,  json  is coming in hierarchical, but in my case its coming as a plain text,.

Comment: Is encoding the JSON required to use it as a data URI? Since that obv mangles the JSON a bit by escaping.

Comment: @AdityaKumar JSON is always just text. no hierarchical whatever. What you mean is a JS object. The only formatting for JSON is the addition of line breaks and spaces/tabs for better readability. You can have notepad++ interpret your JSON as JS by simply switching the language.

Comment: If you would like newlines to appear in your JSON, and indentation, then use the other arguments of `JSON.stringify`, like: `ob2=JSON.stringify(c1, null, 2);`

Comment: Actually here I am trying to separate multiple child object from one json, as a seperate json file but after saving its format is not as a json.

Comment: @trincot You got my point and its working, but for text which I have added are coming in same line, I want a new line after '{' but don't know how to put a new line.

Comment: var obj1="{ \"tagClassifications\": "+ob2+" }"; In this Line after '{' I want to add a new line , \n is working here. Thank you all.

Comment: That clarified your question ;-) But I would advise not to manipulate the JSON output yourself. Instead, first add the *tagClassifications* key in a native JavaScript object, and then stringify that. I have put this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In comments it was clarified that you were looking for ways to get the JSON string split over multiple lines, with indentation.

For that you can use the third argument of `JSON.stringify`. Also, it would be best to delay this conversion to JSON string until after you have constructed the whole object, so including the *tagClassigifications* or *tagAssociations* key name.

The part dealing with *tagClassigifications* would look like this:

```
var c1 = obj[i];
var obj2 = { tagClassifications: c1 }; // first build the object
var json = JSON.stringify(obj2, null, 2); // only then stringify
console.log(json);
```

You would do a similar thing for the *tagAssociations*.